# How to sort a multidimensional array in in php

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array in php and I want to sort it according to the entered time, but I can't so please give some ideas.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [account_id] => 9
            [entered] => 1369374812
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [account_id] => 9
            [entered] => 1377587453
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [account_id] => 9
            [entered] => 1373542381
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [account_id] => 9
            [entered] => 1372988725
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [account_id] => 353
            [entered] => 1380191316
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [account_id] => 9
            [entered] => 1377587610
        )
)
```

Comment: Same as all the other thousands of array sorting questions: either usort() or array_multisort()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
function aasort (&$array, $key) {
    $sorter=array();
    $ret=array();
    reset($array);
    foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
        $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
    }
    asort($sorter);
    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
        $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
    }
    $array=$ret;
}

aasort($your_array,"account_id");
```

Comment: thanks rohan its work!  i want to sort it 'DESC' order, i try to change the sorting order but it not working proper after change the order.

Comment: Use `asort(array_reverse($sorter));` in place of `asort($sorter);` and try

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
//in PHP 5.5:
$rgOrder = array_column($rgData, 'entered');
array_multisort($rgOrder, SORT_ASC, $rgData);
```

if you have PHP older than 5.5, then:

```
$rgOrder = array_map(function($rgItem)
{
   return $rgItem['entered'];
}, $rgData);
array_multisort($rgOrder, SORT_ASC, $rgData);
```

-you can find a fiddle [here](http://3v4l.org/lF5Og). If you don't want to use `array_multisort` (since it requires to create temporary array first), you can act like:

```
usort($rgData, function($rgX, $rgY)
{
   return $rgX['entered']>$rgY['entered']?-1:$rgX['entered']!=$rgY['entered'];
});
```

-here's [fiddle](http://3v4l.org/QbZ67) for it. All samples require at least PHP 5.3. Otherwise you need to use `create_function` for callback definitions.

Comment: hi Alma my array is $finalArray and i want to sort it in DESC order but i can't do this using your code please help me. and my PHP version is 5.2.9  thanks

Comment: Then may be it's `array_multisort($rgOrder, SORT_DESC, $finalArray);` ? (`$rgOrder` is generated same way)

Comment: sorry Alma it is not working i replaced $rgData to $finalArray but its not working

Comment: @sandy - strange. Added fiddle. Anyway, you could try `usort` option.

Comment: Be aware that the second example will only work in `5.3+`. If you run less then that you need to use a function name instead of an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the sorting using [usort](http://php.net/usort)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 0);

function compare($a, $b) {
        if ( $a['entered'] == $b['entered'] ) {
                return 0;
        }

        return ( $a['entered'] < $b['entered'] ) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(
        array('account_id' => 9, 'entered' => 1369374812),
        array('account_id' => 9, 'entered' => 1377587453),
        array('account_id' => 9, 'entered' => 1373542381)
);

usort($a, "compare");

print_r($a);
?>
```